# javascript redirection issue

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

i have 2 php files  aff.php and goaff.php

in aff.php i execute some functions and then redirect the user to goaff.php

aff.php code

```
<?
 here some php functions excuted
?> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.replace("http://www.example.com/goaff.php?id=text");
</script>
</head>
```

in goaff.php also i execute another php code and then redirect to website

goaff.php code

```
<?
here an php function excuted using id from aff.php then redirect

$url = "http://www.example.com";
header("Location: $url");
?>
```

my issue is with aff.php , with some users it doesn't redirect to goaff.php at all , i have test it by tracking the id from aff.php and log the results in a database , i need to know if there is something wrong with the redirection method in aff.php or not , i used javascript top.location.replace to prevent embedding the page inside frames and also to get sure javascript is enabled in the user browser but it logs more than 40% from the users are not redirected to goaff.php

Comment: Why don't you redirect the users with PHP?

Comment: adding 'return(false);' after your top.location.replace() could do the trick.

Comment: i used javascript top.location.replace to prevent embedding the page inside frames and also to get sure javascript is enabled in the user browser

Comment: `also to get sure javascript is enabled` So maybe 40% of hits to `aff.php` are webbots, without js enabled.

Comment: Steve is almost certainly correct if this is a forward facing website with any decent traffic.

Comment: Steve, its affiliates system,  i have to do it in 2 steps to record a hits for the affiliate user, if i keep all tasks in aff.php it will record bots, its impossible the 40% are bots because i know the traffic sources

Comment: That its an affiliate system adds weight nto my theory that 40% are bots! Either way, the code looks fine so the issue is elswhere - if not bots, maybe the code in aff.php just runs too slowly, so people are closing the browser window before the javascript is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your problem is with redirection:

if that's the problem ,  use:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/goaff.php?id=text"
```

instead of

```
top.location.replace("http://www.example.com/goaff.php?id=text");
```

Comment: hmm , then  Why you are not redirecting users with PHP ? :-/

Comment: window.location.replace('http://www.google.com') works the same as window.location = 'http://www.google.com' (Due to .replace() just being a string method on the window.location string) and top always references the top most window in javascript, which can just == window